# Swift, iOS- NSUserDefaults for days active? Only increment int when it is the first time they opened app on THAT DAY?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store an int in NSUserDefaults for the number of days active. Here is how I've been incrementing my NSUSerdefaults:

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    class func incrementIntegerForKey(key:String) {
        let defaults = standardUserDefaults()
        let int = defaults.integerForKey(key)
        defaults.setInteger(int+1, forKey:key)
    }
}
```

Then I call:

```
NSUserDefaults.incrementIntegerForKey("daysActive")
```

I need to increment the int at this key ONLY if it is (not the first time opening the app ever) but the first time they opened the app THAT DAY. Originally I thought of calling this is `viewDidLoad` however that could be incremented multiple times in 1 day.

Is there a way to do this? 
I thought of setting a boolean in NSUserDefaults but I don't know how to reset this boolean every time its a new day, detecting timezones, etc.

How I can count days active?

Using the extension:

```
NSUserDefaults.incrementIntegerForKey("daysActive")
```

Comment: You should store the last day you incremented in userdefaults. Then test if it is the same day or not before incrementing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this `NSDate` extension will make things easier

```
extension NSDate {
    var isToday: Bool {
        let now = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: NSDate())
        let this = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: self)
        return now.year == this.year && now.month == this.month && now.day == this.day
    }
}
```

Now your extension can be written as follow

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    class func incrementIntegerForKey(key:String) {
        let lastIncreased = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("lastCheck_\(key)")
        let alreadyIncreasedToday = lastIncreased?.isToday ?? false

        if !alreadyIncreasedToday {
            let counter = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(key)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(counter + 1, forKey: key)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "lastCheck_\(key)")
        }
    }
}
```

> Please note that this `incrementIntegerForKey` is **NOT** thread safe.

Comment: So first I need to make a new key as an NSDate for the last time this was checked correct?

Comment: @skyguy: My extension `incrementIntegerForKey` already does that.

Comment: Ive updated my question with how Ive implemented your extension (obviously can't test until the next day) but thank you I assume it works - am I using it correctly?

Comment: Or do I need to do something else first

Comment: @skyguy: Yep, you are using it the right wait. No additional code is needed.

Comment: @skyguy: If you want to test it you can just manually change the date of the iOS Simulator

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you could do that - how?

Comment: Ops... actually it looks like you'll need to run the app on a real iPhone/iPad to change the date.